# Program (nload) runs as a daemon when executed in shell but not in startup/automation script

Tags: c++, linux, bash, shell, automation

I would like to run nload (a network throughput monitor) as a daemon on startup (or just automate in general). I can successfully run it as a daemon from the command line by typing this:

```
nload eth0 >& /dev/null &
```

Just some background: I modified the nload source code (written in C++) slightly to write to a file in addition to outputting to the screen. I would like to read the throughput values from the file that nload writes to. The reason I am outputting to /dev/null is so that I don't need to worry about the stdout output.

The weird thing is that, when I run it manually it runs just fine as a dameon and I am able to read throughput values from the file. But every attempt at automation has failed. I have tried init.d, rc.local, cron but no luck. The script I wrote to run this in automation is:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "starting nload"
/usr/bin/nload eth0 >& /dev/null &
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo started nload
else
    echo failed to start nload
fi
```

I can confirm that when automated, the script does run, since I tried logging the output. It even logs "started nload", but when I look at the list of processes running nload is not one of them. I can also confirm that when the script is run manually from the shell, nload starts up just fine as a daemon.

Does anyone know what could be preventing this program from running when run via an automated script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like nload is crashing if it's not run from terminal.

```
viroos@null-linux:~$ cat /etc/rc.local
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.

strace -o /tmp/nload.trace /usr/bin/nload

exit 0
```

looks like HOME env var is missing:

```
viroos@null-linux:~$ cat /tmp/nload.trace
brk(0x1f83000)                          = 0x1f83000
write(2, "Could not retrieve home director"..., 34) = 34
write(2, "\n", 1)                       = 1
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

lets fix this:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.

export HOME=/tmp
strace -o /tmp/nload.trace /usr/bin/nload

exit 0
```

we have another problem:

```
viroos@null-linux:~$ cat /tmp/nload.trace
read(3, "\32\1\36\0\7\0\1\0\202\0\10\0unknown|unknown term"..., 4096) = 320
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f23e62c9000, 4096)            = 0
ioctl(2, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, 0x7ffedd149010) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
ioctl(2, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, 0x7ffedd148fb0) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
write(2, "Error opening terminal: unknown."..., 33) = 33
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

I saw you mentioned that you modified nload code but my guess is you haven't removed handling missing termin. You can try further editing nload code or use screen in detached mode:

```
viroos@null-linux:~$ cat /etc/rc.local
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.

export HOME=/tmp
screen -S nload -dm /usr/bin/nload


exit 0
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to figure this out! You were spot on. It works like a charm now! strace looks like a really useful tool. I will use it in the future.